# JavaScript minification in .NET with YUI

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, yui-compressor

I'm using a BundleCollection to combine and minify my JavaScript in a .NET MVC project. I would like to use YUI Compressor to minify instead of whatever it's currently using. The code is like this, in Global.asax:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/out").Include("~/assets/js/*.js"));
```

This is combining the files alright and minifying them, but I'd like it to use YUI. Thanks!

Comment: any particular reason or just preference?

Comment: mostly just preference, like being able to include certain comments in my minified scripts. if there are other ways of combining and minifying scripts that dont involve scriptbundles or yui, id be interested in that too.

Comment: most minifiers will respect the important comment marker `/*! comment.... */`

Comment: Do a NuGet search for Yui compressor and you'll find packages to work with the bundler to replace the default one.

Comment: @Jasen example of how i would replace the default one?

Comment: You replace the `bundle.Transforms.Add(new YuiTransformer())`. Exact code depends on the transformer you choose but they implement `IBundleTransform` which lets you swap transforms.

Comment: @jasen ah got it! its surprisingly hard for me to find documentation on some of these; thank you!

Comment: Try this link http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Bundle%20Transformer%201.7.27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a NuGet search for YUI Compressor and you'll find packages to replace the default one.

Basically they all work the same by plugging in a new `IBundleTransform` implementation.

```
var scriptBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js").Include("...");
scriptBundle.Transforms.Add(new YuiJsTransformer());
```